# Creating a nested key/value pair in R from data frame

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, key-value, csvtojson

I'm attempting to convert a csv into JSON format for the first time. When the csv is read into R, it's in the following data frame format:

```
col1   col2   col3
1       a      def1
1       b      def2
2       c      def3
2       a      def1
```

Ideally, I'd like to iterate through the dataframe, find the unique combinations of the three columns, and separate the key/value pairs for the JSON into the following:

```
{ "1":["a", "def1"], ["b", "def2"], "2":["a", "def1"], ["c", "def3"]}
```

I can only think of ways to achieve this in python, but I'm having difficulties executing this in R. Any suggestions on how to get this started?

Comment: I think there should be another `[]` to enclose the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `split` the `unname`d subset of columns (without the 'col1') by 'col1', and apply `toJSON` on it

```
library(jsonlite)
toJSON(split(unname(df1[-1]), df1$col1))
#{"1":[["a","def1"],["b","def2"]],"2":[["c","def3"],["a","def1"]]}
```

---

If it needs to be `order`ed

```
toJSON(split(unname(df1[do.call(order, df1[1:2]),-1]), df1$col1))
#{"1":[["a","def1"],["b","def2"]],"2":[["a","def1"],["c","def3"]]}
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), col2 = c("a", "b", "c", 
"a"), col3 = c("def1", "def2", "def3", "def1")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```